# How to customise gray colours in material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm wanting to use material UI for a project. I see in the documentation that is possible to add a custom theme to change the colours of primary, secondary, etc.

Is it possible to do the same thing for other colours? For example, is it possible to create a theme for the grays used by material UI, without having to manually write custom css for each component?

Answer (score 0):

you change it on theme file :

```
    import { red } from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

// A custom theme for this app
const theme = createTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiFormLabel: {
      asterisk: {
        color: '#db3131',
        '&$error': {
          color: '#db3131'
        },
        '&$warning': {
          color: '#db3131'
        },
      }
    }
  },
  colorMenu:'#fff',
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#009788',
    },
    gray: {
      main: '#B1B6C0',
    },
    action: {
      main: '#daa081',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#db3131',
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400,
    },
    background: {
      default: '#fff',
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```